React native android cli build issue || react-native-vision-camera:compileDebugKotlin FAILED
After installing the package "react-native-vision-camera": "^4.0.5" when I try to build the Android apk I get the error I get this error
android/build.gradle
react-native-version

VisionCamera does not support RN 0.74 yet. source
See more update on the issue
To address the problem, you could implement a small patch for those experiencing a build issue.
diff --git a/node_modules/react-native-vision-camera/android/src/main/java/com/mrousavy/camera/frameprocessors/VisionCameraProxy.kt b/node_modules/react-native-vision-camera/android/src/main/java/com/mrousavy/camera/frameprocessors/VisionCameraProxy.kt
index d697befe..8de418b0 100644
--- a/node_modules/react-native-vision-camera/android/src/main/java/com/mrousavy/camera/frameprocessors/VisionCameraProxy.kt
+++ b/node_modules/react-native-vision-camera/android/src/main/java/com/mrousavy/camera/frameprocessors/VisionCameraProxy.kt
@@ -7,12 +7,14 @@ import com.facebook.jni.HybridData
 import com.facebook.proguard.annotations.DoNotStrip
 import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext
 import com.facebook.react.bridge.UiThreadUtil
+import com.facebook.react.common.annotations.FrameworkAPI
 import com.facebook.react.turbomodule.core.CallInvokerHolderImpl
 import com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIManagerHelper
 import com.mrousavy.camera.core.ViewNotFoundError
 import com.mrousavy.camera.react.CameraView
 import java.lang.ref.WeakReference
 
+@OptIn(FrameworkAPI::class)
 @Suppress("KotlinJniMissingFunction") // we use fbjni.
 class VisionCameraProxy(private val reactContext: ReactApplicationContext) {
   companion object {


